# iOS app not being copied to simulator

Tags: ios-simulator

An iPad app I'm starting compiles and builds fine, I get a packaged application. But when I try to debug it, it fails with "Unknown error" after trying to install in the simulator. Inspecting the simulator directory, no Application sub-dir for my app is ever created.

It works perfectly for other iPad projects and I'm not really sure where to start - what does this imply is wrong inside my package? Does the simulator inspect the package before installing it?

I should add, this XCode project was a working iOS sample app that previously DID deploy and run on the simulator. I have only changed the source files and linked in some additional libs, not changed the underlying project structure. I don't expect it to run without errors, but I did expect it to at least start up!

Comment: Have you checked the owner/group of your `~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator` directory?

Comment: No. But as I said, this is the only app with this problem. And it only started having problems after I messed about with the code, so I can't believe it is a systemic problem.